# [[maybe_unused]] for a function

Tags: c++

I don't quite understand when `[[maybe_unused]]` on a function itself could be useful.

By reading [the paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0212r1.pdf), it only said the attribute may be applied to the declaration of a function. My question is that if it implies compiler will raise warning on an unused function, then for any public header of a library, everything should have the attribute to avoid warning as users might only use parts of the library.

Is my understanding correct?

Thank you.

Comment: _"...everything should have the attribute..."_ - Declaration imply external (as there is no definition) and therefore the compile can't reason about the use of a function in a particular translation unit as it may be used in another translation unit.

Comment: Essentially what this does is stop the compiler from alerting the user that the declared entity with this attribute is not used.

Comment: The problem with OP's reasoning lies in his understanding of the compiler, not the understanding of the maybe_unused attribute IMO.

Comment: In a header any definition of a function should be inline and that already avoids the warning. Declarations of functions on the other hand already don't give the warning. So that takes care of headers. The attribute is only sensible during development when you have a function you will be using in the future and want to compile it without warning for the time being.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inspired from [here](https://riptutorial.com/cplusplus/example/19126/--maybe-unused--):

```
namespace {
    [[maybe_unused]] void foo() {}
    void bar() {}
}

int main() {}
```

Functions declared in the unnamed namespace can only be used in this translation unit, hence the compiler can warn when the functions are not used. And indeed gcc warns for `bar` (error because of `-Wall -Werror`) but due to `[[maybe_unused]]` not for `foo` :

```
<source>:5:10: error: 'void {anonymous}::bar()' defined but not used [-Werror=unused-function]
    5 |     void bar() {}
      |          ^~~
```

[Live](https://godbolt.org/z/onxhqMh8E)

The original example in the page linked above is a little more motivating, as it uses conditional compilation where depending on some symbols being set a function is used or not.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler warns about functions that it can tell are unused. If it is unsure - if your function ends up in a place where others could call it, like in a library - the compiler assumes it is used.

For example, if you have a translation unit with these functions ([ref](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/9fEcsjWes)):

```
int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

static int cube(int num) {
    return num * num * num;
}
```

`square` could be called by other functions from other translation units. It's unused *here* but may be used somewhere else. The compiler doesn't know about these other places, so it cannot flag the function as unused. There is no warning; adding the attribute has no effect.

`cube`, on the other hand, is `static` - so if it's used anywhere, it must be in this translation unit. Since it isn't used here, the compiler (at least `gcc` with `-Wunused-function`) warns about this.

Adding `[[maybe_unused]]` to `cube` then silences that warning. It basically says "I know that you know that this is unused; don't warn about it."